# Ignore/Overcome "Invalid range end" in grep

Tags: grep, range

Tried `grep -xf test $option` in a bash script, searching for test file as pattern in option file. Despite that in some cases test matches exactly in option, I take 
`grep: Invalid range end`
How can I avoid it? Something wrong with escaping quotes maybe? -e and -E options didn't work.

Comment: This means that the file `test` contains some invalid patterns.

Comment: An online diff tool I used shows test and pattern from option identical